# Using Sumifs on a range in a separate spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently preforming a Sumifs calculation using the follow code

```
 Public Function WFPAID(rev_date As Date) As Variant

  Application.Volatile (True)

  Set Vstatus = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$DL:$DL")
  Set Team = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$DO:$DO")
  Set WF_Paydate = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$DK:$DK")

            WFPAID = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs( _
            Writer_Fee _
            , Team, "<>9" _
            , Vstatus, "<>rejected", Vstatus, "<>unverified" _
            , WF_Paydate, rev_date)

 End Function
```

The name of my Excel file is `DATADUMP` and is saved on our server in the following location `U:\DATADUMP.xlsx`. I would like to preform the Sumifs calculation in `U:\DATADUMP.xlsx` Sheet. `KRONOS` from a different Excel called `NEWCAL`.

Can one help please.

Comment: Will the result be outputted into `DATADUMP.xlsx` or will the result be outputted to somewhere in `NEWCAL.xlsx`

Comment: Hi Hari, I want to do the same Sumifs calculation (as in my posting) in NEWCAL.XLSX on ranges in sheets KRONOS in DATADUMP.XLSX

Comment: It looks like you are using this as a User Defined Function. AFAIK you are not able to use a UDF to access another workbook from within the UDF. There are a number of things you can do, including setting up `DATADUMP.xlsx` as a data source for `NEWCALC.xlsx` and running your UDF from `NEWCALC.xlsx` for the imported data. Another option is to completely forgo a UDF and use some vba code to read the data and process as you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Paste this code into a module in `NEWCALC.xlsx` and run as a macro. It will output the result of the SumIfs calculation to a cell in `NEWCALC`.

```
Sub CalculateSumIfsOnDATADUMP()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Vstatus As Range, Team As Range, WF_Paydate As Range, Writer_Fee As Range
Dim WFPAID As Variant
Dim rng As Range
Dim colCOUNT As Long

    '// turn off screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '// open the source workbook as read only
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("U:\DATADUMP.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)

    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Activate

    For Each rng In Application.Selection
    rev_date = rng.Value

        With wb.Worksheets("KRONOS")

            '// Set range variables for SumIfs calculation
            '// (NOTE: 'Writer_Fee' range needs to be supplied)
            Set Writer_Fee = .Range("Something")
            Set Vstatus = .Range("$DL:$DL")
            Set Team = .Range("$DO:$DO")
            Set WF_Paydate = .Range("$DK:$DK")

            '// Do the SumIfs Calculation, and store in WFAID
            WFPAID = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Writer_Fee, _
                                                          Team, "<>9", _
                                                          Vstatus, "<>rejected", _
                                                          Vstatus, "<>unverified", _
                                                          WF_Paydate, "=" & rev_date)
        End With

        '// Output the calculation result to a cell in the ActiveSheet
        ActiveSheet.Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column + Selection.Columns.Count) = WFPAID

    Next rng

    '// close the source workbook without saving any changes
    wb.Close False

    '// turn on screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**EDIT**
I changed the code to read a selected range, and output the SumIfs result in the column next to it.

Comment: Thank you so much.  As I use the function so I can create Table with diffrent dates can I not run your code as a FUNCTION?

Comment: @Fred: Im sure it can be redone as a function, but it will still need called from a `sub`. Ive kept it strictly as a `sub` to read the selected range of cells and use those values in the `SumIfs` calculation. It will output the results next to the selected cells. Adjust as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "DATADUMP.xlsx" is already open, you might try something like this:

```
Public Function WFPAID(rev_date As Date) As Variant
   Dim objWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Dim objWriterFee As Excel.Range
    Dim objStatus As Excel.Range
    Dim objTeam As Excel.Range
    Dim objPaydate As Excel.Range

    Application.Volatile (True)

    ' This assumes "DATADUMP.xlsx" is already open.
    Set objWorksheet = Application.Workbooks("DATADUMP.xlsx").Worksheets("KRONOS")

    ' Change the next line to set the "writer fee" to a valid range.
    Set objWriterFee = objWorksheet.Range("?")
    Set objStatus = objWorksheet.Range("$DL:$DL")
    Set objTeam = objWorksheet.Range("$DO:$DO")
    Set objPaydate = objWorksheet.Range("$DK:$DK")

    WFPAID = _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs _
        ( _
             objWriterFee, _
             objTeam, "<>9", _
             objStatus, "<>rejected", objStatus, "<>unverified", _
             objPaydate, rev_date _
        )
End Function
```

However, if "DATADUMP.xlsx" is *not* already open, you can't open it in the current application during recalculation.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I used your code but the WFPAID function gives #VALUE.  It appears no value is being returned.

Comment: Here are some suggestions that might help identify the source of the problem:  a) Is "DATADUMP.xlsx" is already open?  b) Did you modify the code I posted to correctly set the "objWriterFee" range to a valid range?  It was not obvious from your original post as to how this range was defined.  c) Place a breakpoint in the function and verify that the ranges are being set correctly when the function is called during a recalculation.  d) Does an equivalent SUMIFS expression in a worksheet cell in the "NEWCAL.xlsx" worksheet give you the answer you expect (details follow in next comment)?

Comment: The equivalent SUMIS expression should look something like this, assuming you replace the <writer fee range> and <revision date> appropriately: `=SUMIFS('[DATADUMP.xlsx]KRONOS'!<writer fee range>, '[DATADUMP.xlsx]KRONOS'!$DO:$DO, "<>9", '[DATADUMP.xlsx]KRONOS'!$DL:$DL, "<>rejected", '[DATADUMP.xlsx]KRONOS'!$DL:$DL, "<>unverified", '[DATADUMP.xlsx]KRONOS'!$DK:$DK, <rev_date>)`

Comment: Thank you.  I will try that and keep you posted

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post another method for doing this that I did not know was possible. According to [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/writingfunctionsinvba.aspx), you can:

> call a UDF that is contained in another (open) workbook by using the workbook name in the formula. For example: `='MyBook.xls'!RectangleArea(A1,A2)`

So this means that another method of calling your UDF would be to make sure the other WB is open: `Workbooks.Open("U:\DATADUMP.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)`

Then in the other worksheet, make sure the function reads like this:
    `='DATADUMP.xlsx'!WFPAID([Cells reference to dat])`

It seems a much simpler way of implementing your objective. You could accompany this with vba if you needed to, but you could also limit when the sheet calculates, or do a `copy`-`pasteValues` to preserve the results.

Comment: Thank you very kindly for your suggestion.  Will give it a try.